# PyQt5 add a scrollbar to main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I know there are already lots of threads opened with this topic, I was trying to follow their recommendations, but I still struggle to achieve this.

Here is my initial code for window:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        emphysemaLabel = QLabel("EMPHYSEMA", self)
        emphysemaLabel.move(10, 10)

        ggoLabel = QLabel("GGO", self)
        ggoLabel.move(10, 300)

        condensLabel = QLabel("Condens", self)
        condensLabel.move(10, 590)

        emphysema_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        emphysema_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        emphysema_graph_lin.move(10, 50)
        emphysema_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")

        ggo_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        ggo_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        ggo_graph_lin.move(10, 340)
        ggo_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")

        condens_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        condens_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        condens_graph_lin.move(10, 630)
        condens_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

An example if what I found useful and working is code found here https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qscrollarea/

I tried to apply it to my code, like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()  # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
        self.widget = QWidget()  # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()  # The Vertical Box that contains the Horizontal Boxes of  labels and buttons

        emphysemaLabel = QLabel("EMPHYSEMA", self)
        emphysemaLabel.move(10, 10)
        self.vbox.addWidget(emphysemaLabel)

        ggoLabel = QLabel("GGO", self)
        ggoLabel.move(10, 300)
        self.vbox.addWidget(ggoLabel)

        condensLabel = QLabel("Condens", self)
        condensLabel.move(10, 590)
        self.vbox.addWidget(condensLabel)

        emphysema_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        emphysema_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        emphysema_graph_lin.move(10, 50)
        emphysema_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(emphysema_graph_lin)

        ggo_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        ggo_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        ggo_graph_lin.move(10, 340)
        ggo_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(ggo_graph_lin)

        condens_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        condens_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        condens_graph_lin.move(10, 630)
        condens_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(condens_graph_lin)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        # Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

But it's not working, how should I do it?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean that it's not working? Are you referring to the fact that you see the labels are occupying the whole space? If that's the case, that's completely expected, because you're using a layout manager, which makes manually setting geometries (move(), resize()) completely pointless: it's called layout *manager*, its purpose is to manage and optimize sizes, and even empty labels and spaces are considered wasted space unless they can expand. If you want to respect minimum sizes, use setMinimumSize() (or related functions), if you want spacers, call addSpacing().

Comment: the scroll bar is not working

Comment: The contents can perfectly fit the size of your window and are also automatically adapted by the layout manager to fill the remaining available space: the scroll bar *is* working, the point is that there is absolutely *nothing* to scroll. Try to resize the window to a size smaller than the minimum required by those widgets, and then you'll see. As already said, if you want your widgets to have a minimum size, you have to explicitly do that, otherwise the layout manager will shrink or expand them as much as possible.

Comment: Is there another way to add scroll bar? To be able to keep move() and resize

Comment: I've already written what you can do. Read more carefully and search the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a vertical spacer at the end of the layout using the `addStretch()` method of the QVBoxLayout object.
And adjust the maximum size to view the scroll working, `setMaximumSize()`.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        
        # set maximum size of the QMainWindow
        self.setMaximumSize(600, 100)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()  # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
        self.widget = QWidget()  # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()  # The Vertical Box that contains the Horizontal Boxes of  labels and buttons

        emphysemaLabel = QLabel("EMPHYSEMA", self)
        emphysemaLabel.move(10, 10)
        self.vbox.addWidget(emphysemaLabel)

        ggoLabel = QLabel("GGO", self)
        ggoLabel.move(10, 300)
        self.vbox.addWidget(ggoLabel)

        condensLabel = QLabel("Condens", self)
        condensLabel.move(10, 590)
        self.vbox.addWidget(condensLabel)

        emphysema_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        emphysema_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        emphysema_graph_lin.move(10, 50)
        emphysema_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(emphysema_graph_lin)

        ggo_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        ggo_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        ggo_graph_lin.move(10, 340)
        ggo_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(ggo_graph_lin)

        condens_graph_lin = QLabel(self)
        condens_graph_lin.resize(302, 232)
        condens_graph_lin.move(10, 630)
        condens_graph_lin.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        self.vbox.addWidget(condens_graph_lin)
        
        #  add a vertical spacer with addStretch() method
        self.vbox.addStretch()

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        # Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```